# python aggregating groupby using a default func

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

I have a large dataframe with > 100 columns, I want to group it by id column and take first value of most columns but I want to provide specific aggregation function for a few column. Looking for a simple way to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    name  score_1  score_2  score_3.........score_100
0   Foo        5       10       10            10
1  Baar       10       15       20            10
2   Foo       15       10       30            10
3  Baar       10       25       40            10
```

I want to group above dataframe by name keeping 'first' value of column score _1 to score_98 and 'sum' of score_99 and 'mean' of score_100

I have tried using df.groupby(name).agg(collate).reset_index(), need help writing the collate function or a better way to do this. Thanks

Comment: Try `.agg({'score_99': 'sum', 'score_100': 'mean'})`

Comment: that would just give me these 2 columns in the dataframe, I want 'first' value for all others as well

Comment: see @jpp answer, same direction I was going

Comment: *I have a large dataframe with > 100 columns*... your first and only problem. Reshape dataframe to long format and you can run `groupby` aggregating by *score* indicators. The posted answer does not indicate which aggregation was run and shows how a df structure adds to complexity of operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension and combine 2 dictionaries via the syntax `{**d1, **d2}`:

```
funcs = {**{'score_'+str(i): 'first' for i in range(1, 3)},
         **{'score_99': 'sum', 'score_100': 'mean'}}

res = df.groupby('name').agg(funcs).reset_index()

print(res)

   name  score_1  score_2  score_99  score_100
0  Baar       10       15        60         10
1   Foo        5       10        40         10
```

The above is run for this example input:

```
print(df)

   name  score_1  score_2  score_99  score_100
0   Foo        5       10        10         10
1  Baar       10       15        20         10
2   Foo       15       10        30         10
3  Baar       10       25        40         10
```